# IntelliJ Live Template groovy script cut'n paste from clipboard

Tags: intellij-idea, clipboard, live-templates

I know this can be done because I've done it before but can't remember how.

You create a live template in IntelliJ and you set a variable called `$GROOVY$` which takes the output of this expression:

```
groovyScript([Some file path])
```

Then you write a Groovy script at the file path in question. The idea is that I'm going to copy some Ivy style dependencies and then paste them as maven style dependencies such that colon separated Ivy specs become XML maven when I paste them.

Specifically what I cannot remember is how to get the live template to pull content from the clipboard.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that I completely follow what you are trying to do but I think the crux of it is this:

> how to get the live template to pull content from the clipboard.

You can do this by defining a parameter named, for example, `$clipboard$` and then associating this variable with the Live Template method: `clipboard()`.

For example, given the following live template:

```
// Here are the contents of the $clipboard$
```

With this value in the system clipboard:

```
foobarbas
```

Then engaging the live template will result in the following ouput:

```
// Here are the contents of the foobarbas
```

Here are some screenshots showing it in action:

- Define the live template:

[image]

- Use the template:

[image]

- Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Here is what I'm trying. I'm creating a variable called $GROOVY$ which takes this expression: groovyScript(C:\path\to\groovy\script.groovy,clipboard())

Comment: This answer describes how to use the `clipboard()` method (i.e. you have to assign it to a live template variable). Have you tried doing that? If not (or if you have and it _somehow_ doesn't achieve what you want) then perhaps you could update your question to (a) provide your live template definition and (b) show your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
groovyScript("return _1.replace(\"-\", \".\")", clipboard())
```

Pull data from example-clipboard-body to example.clipboard.body.